# Unable to Databind localstorage to iron-ajax headers

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using the latest Polymer (1.2.0), and I'm having trouble with databinding from iron-localstorage to the iron-ajax headers field. I'm not seeing the Authorization header set when I inspect the request. I've verified the request works when I just create a valid headers object with no databinding.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it not designed to be used like this?

```
<iron-localstorage name="userToken" value="{{localtoken}}" use-raw></iron-localstorage>

<iron-ajax url="api/twitter/v1/private/gettweets" last-response="{{data}}" auto
           headers= '{"Authorization":"Bearer [[localtoken]]}"'
           handle-as="json">
</iron-ajax>
<iron-list items="[[data.futuretweets]]" as="item">
    <template>
        <div>
            datetime: <span>[[item.datetime]]</span>
            text: <span>[[item.text]]</span>
        </div>
    </template>
</iron-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo error in your compound binding, here is a corrected version:

```
<iron-ajax url="api/twitter/v1/private/gettweets" last-response="{{data}}" auto
           headers= '{"Authorization":"Bearer [[localtoken]]"}'
           handle-as="json">
</iron-ajax>
```

[EDIT] since it is not working, try with a computed function like this:

```
<iron-ajax url="api/twitter/v1/private/gettweets" last-response="{{data}}" auto
           headers='_computeHeaders(localtoken)'
           handle-as="json">
</iron-ajax>
```

where

```
_computeHeaders(localtoken) {
  return {"Authorization": "Bearer " + localtoken};
}
```

Comment: @mrbradford did you fix your issue?

Comment: Hi! I did fix the typo -- unfortunately, it did not fix the issue. There is still no Authorization header being sent. There are no console errors, other than the 500 my server replies when there's a missing Auth header.

Comment: Applied one edit: it's more robust and saves a serialization+deserialization step if you return an object rather than a string from the computed function.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't:

```
_computeHeaders(localtoken) {
  return '{"Authorization":"Bearer ' + localtoken + '"}';
}
```

Instead be:

```
_computeHeaders: function(localtoken){
  return '{"Authorization":"Bearer ' + localtoken + '"}';
}
```

Comment: Both are valid but the latter is supported in more browsers, as the former is part of ES6's improved object literal syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a little workaround.
I'm using loopback with authentication service enabled and I'm saving the authentication token with `iron-localstorage`. The problem I've found is that the "auto" of `iron-ajax` let start the request when any ( almost ) of the `iron-ajax` parameter change. When the request start the `localstorage` value hasn't been populated yet

```
<iron-localstorage name="appdata" value="{{user}}"></iron-localstorage>
```

and

```
<iron-ajax auto="{{user.id}}" headers$='{"Authorization" :"{{user.id}}"}' url="/api/data" handle-as="json" last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>
```

the workaround is inside `auto="{{user.id}}"`. While user isn't loaded the user.id is false. When loaded it become something that match as true. That cause also a change inside the `iron-ajax` header attribute and cause the "auto" request send to get fired.

Comment: I thought $= was only for basic HTML attribute bindings?